# How to send DM on button click discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I to make my bot sending a DM message on button click here is my code:

```
    if(button.id === "onBtn"){
        button.clicker.send('ok')
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide what happens instead. Providing packages you are using and discord.js version could also help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
  if(button.id === "btn1"){
    await button.reply.defer()
    await button.message.channel.send("button green")
  }
})
```

But you really should provide a full code to better understand your issue.